# Click-To-Copy Button with line breaks

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a click-to-copy button that copies text with line breaks. Once I figure this out, I'm going to have multiple buttons on the same page that copy different text, which is why the "p1" is specified. This is the code I have so far:

The issue is I can't figure out how to get the line breaks in the text to copy over.

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="p1" hidden="hidden">
    This is line 1
    This is line 2
  </p>
  <p>
    <br>
    <button onclick="copyToClipboard('#p1')">Copy Text</button>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't (mis)use the id atttribute. You can define a custom `data-*` attribute which is accessible through JS, e.g. `<button id="foo" data-text="This is the first line <br> This is the second line">...</button>`

Comment: Please add all the relevant information to the question. Don't add it as comments.

Comment: I updated my question to have all information I can think to provide. It's my first post and I don't know what I'm doing in life. Hope the new information helps.